# JSDoc: How do I let IntelliSense/TypeScript know about classes from other files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm working on a relatively large project, and I want to add JSDoc to my classes and files to make it a lot easier to develop. I have a getter function for my "Configuration" class/object that returns its instance of a "SQLRegistry" object, which is set later on down the chain.

```js
//configuration.js

/**
 * @returns {SQLRegistry} registry
 */
getRegistry() {
    return this._registry;
}
```

```js
//sqlRegistry.js
const Configuration = require('./configuration');

class SQLRegistry {
    //other code
}
```

Unfortunately, in VS Code with IntelliSense/ESLint, it provides an error saying that it cannot find the class 'SQLRegistry'. In any other situation, I would just import sqlRegistry.js into configuration.js, but in this situation I cannot (because sqlRegistry depends on configuration.js, as you can see above).

[image: TypeScript jsdoc checker gives me an error saying it cannot find name 'SQLRegistry']

Is there some sort of JSDoc comment I can put at the top of the file that tells it to read sqlRegistry.js, so that it becomes aware of the SQLRegistry class? For example, something like:

```js
/**
 * @include {@link ./sqlRegistry.js}
 */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hypothetical `@include {@link ./sqlRegistry.js}` was very close in principal.

The actual way to write this under TypeScript's interpretation of JSDoc syntax is

```
/**
 * @returns {import('./sqlRegistry.js')} registry
 */
getRegistry() {
    return this._registry;
}
```

Note that it is TypeScript that actually powers the VS Code's primary JavaScript features like type inference, not ESLint

This syntax, `import('module-specifier')` in a type position, is known as [*import types*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#import-types), not to be confused with *Type only imports* and was introduced in TypeScript 2.9.

This is not a JSDoc specific feature but rather comes from TypeScript.

The TypeScript language service recognizes the syntax in JSDoc comment locations where a type is expected. Note that the official [TypeScript Handbook states that](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#import-types)

> You can also import declarations from other files using import types. This syntax is TypeScript-specific and differs from the JSDoc standard:

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked perfectly!! Is there an online resource somewhere that explains the TypeScript JSDoc syntax? https://jsdoc.app/tags-returns.html doesn't seem to include that import statement.

Comment: I added a link and explains `import(..)` in type position. For JSDoc support in TypeScript, generally see this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#supported-jsdoc